# Display Suite Region to Block Problem

Tags: display-suite

I am using the display suite region to block, but the content in the region is now displaying on every page of the site and not just the node its meant to display in! Surely this isn't right? Am I missing a trick here?

This is in Drupal 8 if this helps. Thanks in advance!